# Subtract values in an array with a for loop

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

I'm trying to subtract all the values in the array loop, the values are generated randomly, but when I put that y = y - Array[I], it starts as 0-i and then it becomes negative.
But when I put y = Array[I] - y; it also doesn't work, can anybody find me somebody to love, jk, can anybody help me subtract the array values, pls.
Thanks :)

```
srand(time(NULL));
int Array[10],i,y=0;
for( i = 0;i<10;i++){
    Array[i]=rand()%(20+1-5) + 5;
    printf("%d,",Array[i]);
    y = y - Array[i];
    printf("(%d)",y);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: unclear what are you trying to do. subtract from what?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would expect for a sequence of 5, 6, 7, 8? "Doesn't work" isn't a good problem statement.

Comment: Lets say the array is [1,2,3,4,5,6] I want the answer to be (1-2-3-4-5-6) = -19

Comment: Okay, so you need a condition. `if (i == 0) { y = Array[i]; } else {  y -= Array[i]; }` You could also do two passes. Fill the array, set y = Array[0] then loop over the rest while subtracting.

Comment: `y = Array[0]; for( i = 1;i<10;i++){…}`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then you have the right pieces to accomplish creating a random array (with your modulo, range `5` to `28`), and then subtracting each number sequentially to arrive at the negative sum -- you just have them slightly out of order from a scope standpoint.

For example, your computation of `y` should not be printed until you leave the loop. That way your negative sum is printed after the sequence, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int Array[10] = {0}, y = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Array[i] = rand() % (20+1-5) + 5;
        printf (i ? ",%d" : "%d", Array[i]);
        y = y - Array[i];
    }
    printf (" = (%d)\n", y);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Two runs of the code:

```
$ ./bin/array_seq
14,5,12,11,20,13,18,17,5,12 = (-127)

$ ./bin/array_seq
18,20,19,16,20,15,19,17,6,17 = (-167)
```

If this isn't what you intended, let me know and I'm happy to help further.